# bootstrap installation in angular 14 fail

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wanted to install Bootstrap in Angular 14 using "ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" but I get an error in PhpStorm IDEA. What should I do?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mECfV.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEdD0.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Later edit**

Looks like the [latest release v13.0.0](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases/tag/13.0.0) of `ng-bootstrap` adds support for Angular 14.1

**Original answer**

The latest stable version of `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` which today 6/16/2022 is 12.1.2 is designed for Angular 13.

The error you are seeing is due to the fact they have a peerDependecy to Angular 13 in their library.

According to this issue https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4340 they are currently working on releasing a new version that supports Angular 14.
At this time you might get be able to install `ng-bootstrap@next` (which is version `13.0.0-beta.1` that's designed for Angular 14)

Comment: ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@next with Angular 14.0.2 works for me, thanks!